# Sending song data from spotify to a backend, e.g. song title, artist etc.

Tags: jquery, spotify

Is it possible to send song information from Spotify to a backend?

I have created an external php script that inserts POSTed song details into a database. But when I try to use it from the Spotify app, it doesn't work?

Heres my code from my spotify app:

```
var track = playerTrackInfo.data;
var trackdata = [
  { name: 'songtitle', value: track.name},
  { name: 'songartist', value: track.album.artist.name}
];

$.post('http://www.mysite.com/insertdata.php', trackdata).error(function() { console.log("Error"); });
```

The code above just logs "Error" into the console.

I have added "http://www.mysite.com" to the manifest.json file but still no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what errors do you get on your php side?

Comment: None, I tested the php script using test data outside of Spotify and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code works fine now, no idea why it was not working at first. Here it is:

```
var track = playerTrackInfo.data;
var trackdata = [
  { name: 'songtitle', value: track.name},
  { name: 'songartist', value: track.album.artist.name}
];

$.post('http://www.mysite.com/insertdata.php', trackdata).error(function() { console.log("Error"); });
```

The problem could have been because i did not restart Spotify after editing the manifest.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely need to restart Spotify for manifest changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery [post() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) your second parameter (trackdata) must be an object or a string. Try this:

```
$.post(url, {'trackdata[]': trackdata}).error(function() { console.log("Error"); });
```

Comment: Thanks man, I tried this and it inserted blank records into my database... so I reverted back to my original line of code and now it works fine! I have no idea why it wasn't working last night, I haven't changed anything else!

Comment: Also, not sure if you know this but remember to restart spotify when changing the manifest for an application.

Comment: That`s probably where the problem was! I don't think I restarted Spotify after editing the manifest, I was unaware you had to. I have updated my answer just incase it helps anyone else. Thanks!